# Complex analysis, limit

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm stuck with a problem in complex analysis involving limits. Its looking like this:

$$\lim_{z\to i} \frac{z^2+i}{z^4 - 1}.$$ I've been doing what I can with factoring out etc, the answer is supposed to be -1/2 but I don't understand how they achieve, what have I missed?

Comment: First, use $a^2-b^2=(a+b)\times(a-b)$ for denominator.

Comment: In fact, the answer to the question as stated is **NOT** $-1/2$; i seems to be $\infty$.  Note that, although the denominator approaches zero, the numerator does not.

Comment: I think the question is $\displaystyle \frac{z^2+1}{z^4-1}$ and in that case you can use L'Hospital rule

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $\;i\;$ in the numerator is $\;1\;$ (otherwise the limit doesn't exist finitely):$$\frac{z^2+1}{z^4-1}=\frac{z^2+1}{(z^2+1)(z^2-1)}=\frac1{z^2-1}\xrightarrow[z\to i]{}-\frac12$$